# Data Source Injection issue in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have configured a datasource in tomcat 8.5.29 for oracle database in following ways:

Step 1:

edited server.xml in tomcat as follows:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="jdbc/personapp" global="jdbc/personapp" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:<host_name>:1521:<db_name>"
          username="my_user_name" password="my_pwd" 
          maxActive="100" 
          maxIdle="20" 
          minIdle="5" 
          maxWait="10000"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

Step 2:
   edited the context.xml as follows:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/personappLocalDB"
              global="jdbc/personapp"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

I have `DBUtility.java` class as follows:

```
public class DBUtility {

  @Resource(lookup="java:/comp/env/jdbc/personappLocalDB")
  private static DataSource dataSource;

  public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        System.out.println("connection="+connection); 
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
  }
}
```

I am getting following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.adv.dao.DBUtility.getConnection(DBUtility.java:27)
```

DataSource is not getting injected to Java class.

Can anyone figure out the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your utility class isn't `@Named` or an `@EJB`. The `@Resource` annotation will not be processed if it's in a regular POJO.